# game of pig variable not assigning properly

Tags: c#

I am making a game of pig where the user enters a point total to play for and plays against a computer. I made a method for the human turn where the user will roll and if they rolled a 2 through 6 then they can either user r to roll again or h to hold. If they roll 1 the players turn is done and they get no new points. However it says in the do while statement that my gameSelect is unassigned when it is and that pigDiceRoll does not exist in current context.
not sure how to fix this
any help would be appericated

```
static double humanTurn()
{

   double pointTotal = 0 ;
    string gameSelect;

    Console.WriteLine("It's your turn");

    do
    {
        var pigDiceRoll = pigRoll();

        if (pigDiceRoll !=1)
        {


            Console.WriteLine("r to roll or h to hold (r/h)");
            gameSelect = Console.ReadLine();
            pointTotal = pointTotal + pigDiceRoll;
        }



    } while (gameSelect != "h" || pigDiceRoll !=1);
    Console.WriteLine($"Your turn point total is {pointTotal}");
    return pointTotal;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gameSelect` is assigned only when `if (pigDiceRoll !=1)` is true.

You should assign a default value.

---

The code won't compile also because `pigDiceRoll` is declared inside the loop.

You will have to declare it outside of the `do..while` loop.

```
int pigDiceRoll;
do
(...)
```